# Only animate cell from willDisplayCell when user scroll, not after reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitableview

Ok so I have a custom animation being implemented inside `willDisplayCell` method. It is working fine when I scroll the view up and down. When I tap on one of the row, it will be pushed to another view controller to show more details and let user update the data.

The issue is when the user get back to the tableview. I called the `[tableView reloadData]` method inside the `viewWillAppear` to make sure updated data is shown. This will trigger the animation transition that I set up earlier.

My question is: Is there a way to only perform the animation when user scroll up/down the tableview, not when the `reloadData` is called?

If there's a way to mix between the `willDisplayCell` with `scrollViewDidScroll` or something along that line, it would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to reload the table? Can you just get a callback with the changed state and update only that (direct into the cell if it is visible)?

Comment: Yeah, I prefer to reloadData. The example above (about going back from detail VC) is just one scenario. I also have reloadData being called on viewDidLoad, and it doesn't look pretty as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to add a state flag that would tell the `willDisplayCell` whether it should actually animate.

Add a property to your `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldPreventDisplayCellAnimation;
```

Set the property before and after calling `reloadData`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  …
  self.shouldPreventDisplayCellAnimation = YES;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
  self.shouldPreventDisplayCellAnimation = NO:
}
```

Modify `willDisplayCell` to animate on condition

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (!self.shouldPreventDisplayCellAnimation) {
    //animate
  }
}
```

Comment: Theoretically, I thought this is going to work. But when the reloadData finishes, the animation will be trigger. I've checked that the flag has been set correctly.

Comment: However, based on your idea, I think I managed to come out with a workaround. I put the `self.shouldPreventDisplayCellAnimation = NO;` inside the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` method. Seems to be working now! 

I'll accept your answer if there's no other solution to this